# Bluemix Build & Deploy Support for Parallel Streams of Jobs?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, ibm-cloud, devops

Simple enough question, does Bluemix have any support for the parallel running for jobs within bluemix?

I haven't managed to find any indication that it does, but considering that Bluemix Build & Deploy [uses Jenkins under the hood](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/13093/view.html), and there are commonly available and widely used Jenkins plugins which allow jobs to be run in parallel ([Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin), [Multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)); I can see this as a possibility.

Comment: For anyone with a similar interest, though not having tried it myself just yet, there is a  CI/CD tool 'UrbanCode' which I've been informed has seamless integration with Bluemix and could be useful if looking to achieve more extensive workflows than offered through the Build&Deploy pipeline. https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/products/urbancode-deploy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean jobs as part of the Delivery Pipeline service, no, there's currently no support for running jobs in the same pipeline in parallel.

Build & Deploy/Delivery Pipeline no longer uses Jenkins--it's been migrated to Travis, I believe.